# aiogram 3 отследить динамический callback

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

После ввода комманды от пользователя бот выводит список пользователей, каждого в отдельной инлайн кнопоке. Нажимая на кнопку в колбеке передается id пользователя. Как отловить этот колбэк?

```
class TaskCreateFactory(CallbackData, prefix = "task_create"):
    id: int

@dp.message(F.text == "Создать задание")
async def cmd_task(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    await state.set_state(TaskForm.user)
        buttons = []
        for user in User.select():
            buttons.append(
                [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user.name, 
                callback_data=TaskCreateFactory(id=user.id))]
                 )
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=buttons)
        await message.answer("Выберите исполнителя", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query(TaskCreateFactory.filter())
async def process_user(call: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: TaskCreateFactory, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(user=callback_data.id)
    await call.message.answer("Напишите задание")
    await call.answer()
    await state.set_state(TaskForm.text)
```

Сейчас выходит ошибка:

```
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InlineKeyboardButton
callback_data
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=TaskCreateFactory(id=1), input_type=TaskCreateFactory]
```